# C# splits the Payload when sending a byte array with Serial Port

Tags: c#, arrays, serial-port, usb

I am currently trying to send a 64 byte long command to a microchip that is connected via the USB Port. I tried using the `SerialPort.Write` Command to send a byte array, but found out, that it actually splits the Payload into 16 byte packets, sends these individually, with empty NAKs inbetween. My code is as follows:

```
SerialPort Chip = new SerialPort("COM4");
byte[] Reset = new byte[64];
byte[] Command = new byte[64];
Reset[0] = 0x70;
Reset[1] = 0xAB;
Reset[2] = 0xCD;
Reset[3] = 0xEF;
for (int z = 4; z < 64; z++)
{
    Reset[z] = 0x00;
}
for (int z = 0; z < 64; z++)
{
    Command[z] = 0x00;
}
Command[0] = 0x60;
Command[7] = 0x80;
Command[8] = 0x02;
Command[9] = 0x03;
Command[10] = 0x10;
Command[11] = 0x01;
Chip.Open();
Chip.Write(Reset,0,64);
Thread.Sleep(25);
Chip.Write(Command,0,64);
```

Does anyone know of a way to send my command in a single packet?
Furthermore, the same happens when I try to send the 64 byte command with a program called HTerm, while a program someone else wrote in C++ seems to work just fine, but I have very little understanding of C++, so that doesn't help me.

Comment: You should specify BaudRate,Parity, DataBits, StopBits, Handshake for SerialPort the same as is set up on device

Comment: The device uses a BaudRate of 9600, 8 DataBits, 1 StopBit, and no Handshake, which is the default.

Comment: are you familiar with serial port? have you tried sending strings

Comment: I've tried sending strings, the situation remains the same.

Comment: what methods are you using to read/check the results? are you using some mature tools?

Comment: I am using an Ellisys USB explorer set inbetweet my host and the device I try to send to. It allows me to analyze in detail what happened on the USB connection.

Comment: It sounds like you are monitoring the USB side of the USB<>RS232 adapter. Have you checked what is actually coming out of the RS232 adapter?

Comment: There is no RS232 adapter. The microchip I am trying to send a command to simply introduces itself to my computer as a COM port.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "payload" as far as a serial port is concerned.  They are very simple devices and only know about bytes.  So what you receive in one whack is highly unpredictable, however many bytes happen to be available in the driver's receive buffer.  The slower your code or the higher the baudrate, the more you'll get.  16 is not a terribly unusual number for a micro-controller, the typical size of the FIFO buffer on a UART chip and can play a role depending on the interrupt trigger you configure.  But no guarantee whatsoever that it will always be 16.

Comment: But from what the USB explorer tells me, my computer always parts the data I am trying to send in 16 byte sized packets, adds an OUT packet, sends that, and receives an ACK packet in return. I've changed the Baud rate, nothing changes though.
Oddly enough, a program by the manufacturer seems to have no trouble communicating with the chip in form of 64 byte sized packets, though I have no idea how that program works.
Could my issue be caused by how windows handels my request? Do you know what I could do to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried sending the 64 bytes one at a time. As far as a COM port is concerned this should be identical to 64 at once.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used for my application that sends byte-arrays:

```
bytesToSend = new byte[6]
                {
                    0, 5, 0,1, 13,10
                };

                _spManager.sendData(bytesToSend);
```

**sendData function:**

```
 public void sendData(byte[] bytestosend)
        {
          _serialPort.Open();
            StartListening();
            _serialPort.Write(bytestosend, 0, bytestosend.Length);

           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
```

I also had a function that allows to convert hexadecimal stuff (from a textbox) to bytes (in case I had a command that changes (**so an array without a predfined length**):

```
var bytes = tbInput.Text.Split(' ').Select(h => byte.Parse(h, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)).ToArray();


                _spManager.sendData(bytes);
```

**StartListening()**:

```
            /// <summary>
            /// Connects to a serial port defined through the current settings
            /// </summary>
            public void StartListening()
            {
                // Closing serial port if it is open
                if (_serialPort != null && _serialPort.IsOpen)
                        _serialPort.Close();

            // Setting serial port settings
            _serialPort = new SerialPort(
                _currentSerialSettings.PortName,
                _currentSerialSettings.BaudRate,
                _currentSerialSettings.Parity,
                _currentSerialSettings.DataBits,
                _currentSerialSettings.StopBits);

            // Subscribe to event and open serial port for data
            _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(_serialPort_DataReceived);
            _serialPort.Open();
        }
```

Comment: I don't see how this would help, that simply uses the same Write-function, and you haven't specified what the StartListening function does.

Comment: Editing functions or changing a way in which a certain function works can definetely help in the world of programming